# When I use <ul> <li> , how to let the element inside the li float left but the <li>

Tags: html, css

I struggled for this issue for hours, but can't get it work still.

I have the html code like this :

```
 <ul>
    <li><div>aa</div><div>aa11</div><li>
    <li><div>bb</div><div>bb11</div><li>
 </ul>
```

I wondered how to use css to let the `<div>` display in one line each li. But the `<ul><li>` label still have its vertical style.

I am new to CSS, and any help will be thankful.

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/4H8Ja/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul li{
display: table;
}

ul li div{
float: left;
}
```

This will make the `<div>` inside the `<li>` to look side by side.

Comment: sorry , I may not express my question clearly . if use the code above , all the div content will display in one line . but I want to display them in two lines , like this : aa aa11 \n bb bb11

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to add

```
list-style-type: none;
```

in order to get rid of the bullet-points. In addition to what @Viswalinga Surya S said

Doing that, would give you this --> http://jsfiddle.net/A35Fe/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to close your `<li>` tags, you have opening `<li>` tags but you didn't close them with `</li>`. If you want to make `aa` and `aa11` side-by-side you also need to add a `display: inline-block;` style to your `div`s. Here's a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/5wLku/

Here's my solution:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>aa</div><div>aa11</div></li>
    <li><div>bb</div><div>bb11</div></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Updated your code, Here is the JSFiddle link and let me know if you want more change:

[http://jsfiddle.net/h5bMa](http://jsfiddle.net/h5bMa/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>aa</div><div>aaa1</div></li>
    <li><div>bb</div><div>bbb1</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li{
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li style="float:left"><div>aa</div><div>aa11</div></li>
```

and end your list items with 
    `</li>` not with `<li>`